# Newbie react question: Target container is not a DOM element when calling react from html

Tags: reactjs

My plan is to have a html call a react component (to test the react component, so the 1st thing i'm trying is a react class.

This is my the react file

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return React.createElement("h1", {}, "Hello ");
    }
}

const HelloElement = React.createElement(Hello, {name: "World"});
ReactDOM.render(HelloElement, document.getElementById('mydiv'));
```

This is the html file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<body>

<script src="Hello.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

But i get Error Decoder which is Target container is not a DOM element.

How to fix this pls ?

Comment: Your import order is wrong. Put your `<script/>` tag after the `div` declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samuel already wrote it in his comment... you need to put the `<script src="Hello.js">` behind the `div`

The code executes in order, so when `Hello.js` runs, the div with `id='mydiv'` doesn't exist yet. Otherwise your code works just fine. All you need is to make use of that name prop.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
        return React.createElement("h1", {}, "Hello " + this.props.name);
  }
}
const HelloElement = React.createElement(Hello, {name: "World"});
ReactDOM.render(HelloElement, document.getElementById('mydiv'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you use `React.createElement` instead of JSX you also don't need Babel so far.

Comment: A follow up question, in the render(), if i change to        return (<h2>h4</h2>);      it says "Unexpected token <", how to fix it pls ?